# Unwanted XML header string coming in JSON response in iOS

Tags: ios, json

The problem I am facing is, when I am fetching JSON data from the server, XML header string comes along with it. I've tried some code changes, but in vain. The response data is perfect but the problem is the XML header. So as of now, I tried `substring` on the response string and managed to pull out the proper JSON data. But what I want to know is the reason behind this problem and what am I doing wrong here.

This is my JSON retrieving code.

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"myServiceURL"];
NSData *response = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *badStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[response bytes]];
NSString *goodStr = [badStr substringFromIndex:76];
NSString *finalStr = [goodStr substringToIndex:[goodStr length]-9];
NSData *goodData = [finalStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:goodData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

This includes the code for performing substring on the received JSON response.

And here is a sample JSON response that I am receiving.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
[{"Title":"DemoTitle","CreationDate":"06/06/2014","Description":"DemoDescription"}]
</string>
```

Need Guidance. Thanks.

Comment: This is not JSON, it's XML with JSON embedded as a string. You need to get the server to just send you JSON, or you need to process the XML as XML, retrieve the string, and then process that as JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll take a look into it. And can you tell the why its coming in this form ? i.e XML with embedded JSON.

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no idea. You should ask the people who provide the service :) Most likely, the service is vended through some legacy XML or SOAP or something and people have embedded JSON in there for other reasons. Definitely don't just try and get the JSON substring though, that is going to bite you in the future, even if it seems to work now.

Comment: Sure thing. Will definitely have a look into it. Thanks for the clarification !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for whatever reason you can't get the server to stop sending the data in xml with json embedded then you can parse the XML first with [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then parse the JSON from that.

Comment: Probably the only way to do this. Thank you.